# Gets command error and gets_s command error

Tags: c, file-io

I have just started to learn File I/O in C Programming. However, I tried to make my own project which is used to read a created file. Now that I have written my code below could you please find the error and tell me what is wrong. The compiler does not show any kind of error but also it won't run, the compiler just blinks and then quits.

I am using visual studio 2015 for my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
FILE *fPointer;
fPointer=fopen("Database.txt","r");
char text[150];

while(!feof(fPointer))
{
    fgets(text,150,fPointer);
    puts(text);
} 
fclose(fPointer);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not pay attention to the topic. I got that sorted out but forgot to backspace it.

Comment: `but forgot to backspace it` Well, there's that "edit" link right under the post. I wonder what it could possibly be good for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a Console project in Visual Studio, and you're running it by hitting the Debug button (green triangle) or F5.  A black console window flashes briefly onto the screen and then vanishes.

This is normal.  :-)

You are running your code, and it's finishing, and the console window that it runs in is going away when it quits.

To work around this "feature" of Visual Studio, put a breakpoint on the final `return` statement in `main()` (put the cursor on that line and press F9).  Then the program will pause at that line, the console window will still be visible, and you'll be able to see your output.

(Alternatively, don't run it from within Visual Studio, but open a Command Prompt and run it from in there.  But I'd advise against this, because running it in the debugger is so much more useful.)

Comment: Wow your method works.

Comment: Plus I used system("pause") syntax after reading your answer. So basically the problem was that it did not stop and when it reaches return it exits. Thanks bro!

Comment: @KeshavMathur: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  (When you find a question or answer useful, it's polite to click the Upvote button to its left - that's the up-pointing triangle.  Also, when you ask a question and receive answers, you should also click the check mark next to the best answer.)

Comment: oh ok i did not know that. Thank you so much I will do it

Comment: Thank you again and cheers...

Comment: For some reason it says that I need more points to click the upvote button. I dont know why it does that?

Comment: @KeshavMathur: Ah, sorry, I'd forgotten about that.  :-)  You're a bit limited in what you can do until you've earned some reputation - see the "Help" links at the top of the page.

Comment: I ended up with a new error lol